# Local surface fitting to 3d points

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, surface, smoothing

I have set of 3d points, but it contains some outliers. My goal is to map original set of 3d points to "smoothed" set of 3d points and get rid of outliers. The approach I choose is - local surface fitting. I'm using C++ for my application, so I was wondering if this algorithm was already implemented in some library (ideally in opencv)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are very nice methods to remove the outliers from PointCloud in PCL: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/statistical_outlier.php

Its very easy to use. Just follow the instructions on the website.